# Tuple type with hashable items

Tags: swift, associated-types

I'm trying to make a tuple type which has a Hashable item & an Any item, & use it in a custom initializer for Dictionary. However, Swift won't use Hashable in this way, & I'm stuck for an alternative. I don't want to restrict the dictionaries I can create to just using Strings as keys.

```
protocol CollectionInitializeable {
    associatedtype T
    init(items: [T])
}

extension Dictionary: CollectionInitializeable {

    typealias T = (Hashable, Any) // not allowed

    init(items: [T]) {

        self.init()
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: `CollectionInitializeable` yet the initializer takes an `Array`, not any `Collection`. 

Comment: @Alexander Point taken re the name, perhaps I should call the protocol ArrayInitializeable :) - but I've given no indication from this code sample why I've implemented it like this - I don’t think that’s the issue here. If I'm choosing to initialise a dictionary using an array of tuples, that's my call...

Comment: Update: this is unnessary now, thanks to [`Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init) and [`Dictionary.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892961-init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

This is unnessary now, thanks to [`Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127165-init) and [`Dictionary.init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init)

## Original Post:

Are you looking for something like this?

```
protocol CollectionInitializeable {
    associatedtype T
    init<C: Collection>(items: C) where C.Iterator.Element == T
}

extension Dictionary: CollectionInitializeable {
    typealias T = Iterator.Element
    
    init<C: Collection>(items c: C)
    where C.Iterator.Element == T {
        self.init()
        for (key, value) in c {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}

let a = [
    (key: 1, value: "a"),
    (key: 2, value: "b"),
    (key: 3, value: "c")
]

print(Dictionary(items: a))
```

Comment: Thanks, I could do this if I wasn't concerned with the protocol, but the problem with this approach is that I'm not conforming to the protocol. I have other classes which implement the init, & I was hoping to use it here too...

Comment: @SomaMan Edited